# IndexError: list index out of range when using input file with different total lines

Tags: python, json, google-maps, loops, geocoding

I've been running a script to geocode some addresses. I've used an input file (12 lines) and it works fine, but when I used another input file of the same format (25 lines), it throws this error, and the generated output file contains only 12 rows:-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\python_scripts\geocoder_new\geocoder\example_input_and_output\geocoder.py", line 19, in     <module>
    r = geocode(line)
  File "C:\python_scripts\geocoder_new\geocoder\example_input_and_output\geocoder.py", line 8, in     geocode
    info = json.loads(data).get("results")[0].get("geometry").get("location")
IndexError: list index out of range
```

The code is below:-

```
import urllib, json
import csv

def geocode(addr):
    url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=%s&sensor=false" %        (urllib.quote(addr.replace(' ', '+')))
    data = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
    if json.loads(data).get("status") != 'ZERO_RESULTS':
        info = json.loads(data).get("results")[0].get("geometry").get("location")
    else:
        info = {'lat': 'NIL', 'lng': 'NIL'}

    return info

fout = open('input2_25.csv', 'w')
fout.write('ADDRESS\tGPS\n')

with open('input2_25', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        r = geocode(line)    
        gps = ('%s, %s' % (r['lat'], r['lng']))
        add = line.strip()
        fout.write('\t'.join([line[:-1], gps]))
        fout.write('\n')

fout.close()
```

input file for 12 lines:-

```
Kg Sg Nibong,Lubuk,Semerah,Parit Sulong,Batu Pahat,Johor
Kg Parit Bentong,Spg Kiri,Sri Medan,Parit Sulong,Batu Pahat,Johor
Ldg B-1, Yong Peng,Tg Semberong,Yong Peng,Ayer Hitam,Batu Pahat,Johor
Kg Sri Belahan,Sg Kluang,Rengit,Batu Pahat,Batu Pahat,Johor
Parit Besar,Bagan,Semerah,Parit Sulong,Batu Pahat,Johor
Spg Tiga Bagan,Bagan,Semerah,Parit Sulong,Batu Pahat,Johor
Parit Besar,Bagan,Semerah,Parit Sulong,Batu Pahat,Johor
Parit Selulon,Linau,Parit Yaani,Sri Gading,Batu Pahat,Johor
Parit Khalil,Sri Gading,Semarang,Ayer Hitam,Batu Pahat,Johor
Kg Parit Dalam,Sri Medan,Sri Medan,Parit Sulong,Batu Pahat,Johor
Kg Parit Jatuh,Tg Semberong,Yong Peng,Ayer Hitam,Batu Pahat,Johor
Parit Besar,Bagan,Semerah,Parit Sulong,Batu Pahat,Johor
```

Input file for 25 lines:-

```
LOT PT NO.1769, KAWASAN MIEL, PEDAS HALAL PARK,REMBAU,NEGERI SEMBILAN,
KM 13, KAMPUNG BUKIT TEMBAKAU, UMBAI, 77300 MERLIMAU, MELAKA,JASIN,MELAKA,
RUMAH SEMBELIH SHAH ALAM, JALAN UTAS 15/7, 40630 SHAH ALAM, SELANGOR DARUL     EHSAN.,PETALING,SELANGOR
14 JALAN 3 HOUSING TRUST 30250 IPOH PERAK,GOMBAK,SELANGOR
LOT PT NO.1769, KAWASAN MIEL, PEDAS HALAL PARK,REMBAU,NEGERI SEMBILAN,
RUMAH SEMBELIH SHAH ALAM, JALAN UTAS 15/7, 40630 SHAH ALAM. SELANGOR DARUL     EHSAN.,PETALING,SELANGOR,
LOT PT NO 1769, KAWASAN MIEL, PEDAS HALAL PARK,REMBAU,NEGERI SEMBILAN,
5629, RUMAH MURAH, JLN KOLAM AIR, 78000 ALOR GAJAH, MELAKA,ALOR GAJAH,MELAKA,
14 JALAN 3 HOUSING TRUST 30250 IPOH PERAK,GOMBAK,SELANGOR
LOT PT NO.1769 KAWASAN MIEL, PEDAS HALAL PARK,REMBAU,NEGERI SEMBILAN,,
LOT PT NO 1769 KAWASAN MIEL PEDAS HALAL PARK,REMBAU,NEGERI SEMBILAN
RUMAH SEMBELIH SHAH ALAM, JALAN UTAS 15/7, 40630 SHAH ALAM, SELANGOR DARUL     EHSAN.,PETALING,SELANGOR
LOT PT NO.1769, KAWASAN MIEL, PEDAS HALAL PARK,REMBAU,NEGERI SEMBILAN,
89 tanjong keramat kuala selangor selangor,HULU SELANGOR,SELANGOR
LOT PT NO.1769 KAWASAN MIEL, PEDAS HALAL PARK,REMBAU,NEGERI SEMBILAN,,
PT 11883, DESA CEMPAKA 6/2G, BANDAR BARU NILAI, NEGERI SEMBILAN.,GOMBAK,SELANGOR
LOT 9, KAMPUNG BUKIT MARAK BANGGU, 16150 KOTA BHARU, KELANTAN,KOTA BHARU,KELANTAN
NO.20, JALAN 4/4, PETALING JAYA, SELANGOR,GOMBAK,SELANGOR
33, MAIN ROAD, 43900 SEPANG, SELANGAR. ,HULU SELANGOR,SELANGOR
NO.20, JALAN 4/4, PETALING JAYA, SELANGOR,GOMBAK,SELANGOR
RUMAH SEMBELIH SHAH ALAM, JALAN UTAS 15/7, 40630 SHAH ALAM, SELANGOR DARUL     EHSAN.,PETALING,SELANGOR
302-D, TMN BUKIT BARU, BUKIT BERUANG, 75450 MELAKA,MELAKA TENGAH,MELAKA
H.KUAN ENT. KUALA PILAH,NEGERI SEMBILAN,KUALA PILAH,NEGERI SEMBILAN,,
H.KUAN ENT JLN CHANGKAT JERING BT 8,SEGARI PERAK,MANJUNG,PERAK,,
29 LOT 3229 TAMAN BONDA PAYA JARAS DALAM SUNGAI BULOH SELANGOR,PETALING,SELANGOR
```

output for 12-line file:-

```
ADDRESS GPS
Kg Sg Nibong,Lubuk,Semerah,Parit Sulong,Batu Pahat,Johor    NIL, NIL
Kg Parit Bentong,Spg Kiri,Sri Medan,Parit Sulong,Batu Pahat,Johor   NIL, NIL
Ldg B-1, Yong Peng,Tg Semberong,Yong Peng,Ayer Hitam,Batu Pahat,Johor   NIL, NIL
Kg Sri Belahan,Sg Kluang,Rengit,Batu Pahat,Batu Pahat,Johor NIL, NIL
Parit Besar,Bagan,Semerah,Parit Sulong,Batu Pahat,Johor NIL, NIL
Spg Tiga Bagan,Bagan,Semerah,Parit Sulong,Batu Pahat,Johor  NIL, NIL
Parit Besar,Bagan,Semerah,Parit Sulong,Batu Pahat,Johor NIL, NIL
Parit Selulon,Linau,Parit Yaani,Sri Gading,Batu Pahat,Johor NIL, NIL
Parit Khalil,Sri Gading,Semarang,Ayer Hitam,Batu Pahat,Johor    NIL, NIL
Kg Parit Dalam,Sri Medan,Sri Medan,Parit Sulong,Batu Pahat,Johor    NIL, NIL
Kg Parit Jatuh,Tg Semberong,Yong Peng,Ayer Hitam,Batu Pahat,Johor   NIL, NIL
Parit Besar,Bagan,Semerah,Parit Sulong,Batu Pahat,Johor NIL, NIL
```

Output for 25-line file is an empty csv file.

I have a total of 7000 addresses to geocode so splitting the addresses into files with 12 addresses each would be a lot of hassle.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Well, it doesn't look like you have anything inside whatever's returned from `json.loads(data).get("results")`. Are you sure that your if block catches all the instances in which there aren't any results?`

Comment: Can you show us the 12- and 25-line input files? Or, better, a complete stripped-down example (with all of the input embedded, nothing pulled by `urlopen`)? See [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the help for details.

Comment: when you plug in the 25 line file as input, do you get a empty output or a 12 line output?

Comment: I got empty output. The file is there but it's empty

Comment: The geocoder is asynchronous and subject to a quota and rate limit (you can usually geocode ~10 or 11 addresses before getting throttled).  You need to check for a valid status before processing the data. and back off the rate of requests if you hit the rate limit.

Comment: @geocodezip yes you are correct, I got throttled. There is a limit of geocoding 2500 addresses per 24 hours :( I reached the limit while testing the files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that the `json.loads(data).get("results")` does not have a item on index `0`, i.e. its empty.

Try requesting the API url with the variables from the line that fails. Most probably google cant find coordinates for that address

Try putting the results list in a var and then check if it is empty or not:

Something like:

```
results = json.loads(data).get("results")
if results:
    info = results[0].get("geometry").get("location")
else:
    print "no results"
```

Comment: For addresses without coordinates, the function will return NIL. When I used the input with 12 lines, there are some addresses which do not have the coordinates, I've posted the inputs and output in my question

Comment: can you debug what is the actual URL called for the line that it fails

Comment: how do I do that? Sorry novice programmer here

Comment: in the geocode function, just after defining the url variable, print it and see what it contains. That URL is called. Copy it into a browser and see what is the response

Comment: actually I got throttled. Might have to find some other methods to geocode all these addresses